# Issues with displaying mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help with making comments show below my articles. At the moment i'm getting an Undefined Index error for all the mysql_fetch_array() elements returned.

Please where could my problem be coming from.?

Thanks for your time.

Comment Table

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment` (
     `comment_id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_      INCREMENT,
      `article_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
      `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
   `comment_body` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
      `comment_date` datetime NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `comment_id` (`comment_      id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=     latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

About Table

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `about` (
     `about_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
    `about_head` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `about_content` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `about_tags` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `about_created` datetime NOT NULL,
   `about_image` blob NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`about_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `about_id` (`about_id`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=        latin1;
```

Display of Comments

```
   $query6=mysql_query("SELECT c.     username,c.comment_body,c.comment_     date
           FROM comment AS c  
  INNER JOIN about AS a ON
  c.article_id = a.about_id") or die
  (mysql_error()); 


   while ($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc       ($query6)) {

      echo "Comment: "; 
      $comment['comment_body'] ; 
      echo "<br/>" ;           

      echo "Date of Comment: ";
      $comment['comment_date'] ;                       echo "<br/>" ;        

      echo "Commenter: ";
      $comment['username'] ; 
      echo "<br/>" ;           
                 }
```

**UPDATE**

I changed mysql_fetch_array to ,ysqo_fetch_assoc, but i'm still getting the same error....Undefined Index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the way you (can't) type, I'd bet at typo.
Anyway, do a

```
var_dump($comment);
```

inside of the loop and see the actual array content.

Comment: Array(3){["commenter"]=> string(8) "dotman14" ["comment"]=> string(7) "hello" ["Date"]=> string(19) "2012-05-03 23:01:16"}

Comment: But i'm still getting all the Undefined Index errors

Comment: Please tell me can you see a `username` key in this array? What about `comment_date`?

Answer (score 0):

I've Performed a test in my localhost, but i didn't get the problem. However if you face "Undefined Index" problem in the result set then you are typing the index value of array which does not exist in array. do this

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($comment);
echo "</pre>";
```

this will help you to track array's current index values.

you are missing "echo" or "print" before " $comment['......"

Comment: sorry for my bad english